# $\ker A = \{ 0\}$ where $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I struggle with the understanding of how an n x m matrix A can have $ker A = \{ 0\}$. Can someone provide me with an example or an explanation as to why this might be the case for a non quadratic matrix?

Comment: Example: $A=\begin{bmatrix}I\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can A only involve the identity matrix and zero matrices?

Comment: If you have a matrix (square or not square) with kernel $0$ and delete columns, the result is another matrix with kernel $0$

Comment: If you fill in a “tall” matrix with random numbers, you will find (with very high probability) that the matrix will have kernel $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$KerM=\{0\}$ is equivalent to: linear mapping is injective. On the other hand, $KerM=\{0\}$ of a matrix $M\in\mathbb K^{m\times n}$ is equivalent to: $rank(M)=n$. But $rank(M_{m, n})\leq \min\{m,n\}$, so $\mathbb K^{m\times n}$ has some matrices with $KerM=\{0\}$ if and only if $m\geq n$. In the language of vector spaces, $Kerf=\{0\}$ for linear mapping $f:V\to W$ means, that the vector space has the same dimension as its image: $\dim V=\dim f(V)$, that is $n$. See wiki article about [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties).

Comment: Why is $rank(M)=n$. Can't it be that we have m independent rows where m<n?

Comment: Your intuition is right, you probably already have noticed that yes, matrix can have less independent rows than $\min\{m,n\}$. But your original question is: how can non-square matrix have zero kernel? Now if you believe me, this question is equivalent to: how can matrix rank be equal to number of rows? BTW, you shouldn't believe me, just grab some good book on linear algebra and take some time for it to sink in.